# Django Two tables for users authorization

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-authentication, backwards-compatibility

I have to implement a backward-compatible Django server with PHP app. Legacy app is using `LegacyUser` model for authorization which more or less like:

```
class LegacyUser(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
    ...
    other_data_fields
    ...

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
```

In a new system, I do not have to add new records of `LegacyUser` (but I can).

For now, the legacy system does not allow to create multiple users per Group. Actually `LegacyUser` should be considered as a group but I was implemented as a user.

Right now I have to implement multiple `Users` per each `LegacyUser` so I have added proper Django user for authorization like:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    legacy_user = models.ForeignKey(LegacyUser, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['publisher']

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'user'
```

and in `base.py` settings:

```
...
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'api.LegacyUser'

SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=15),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
    'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('Bearer',),
    'USER_ID_FIELD': 'id',
    'USER_ID_CLAIM': 'id',
}

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend', #Supports User
    'common.auth.backends.LegacyBackend'         #Supports LegacyUser
]
...
```

The new application should enable to login both `LegacyUser` and `User`. After authorization LegacyUser.id should be used as USER_ID_CLAIM.

This means if I have one LegacyUser like:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "email": admin@domain.com,
    "password": "hashed_password",
    ...
}
```

And two Users e.g.

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "email": user1@domain.com,
    "password": "hashed_password",
    "legacy_user_id": 1,
    ...
}
```

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "email": user2@domain.com,
    "password": "hashed_password",
    "legacy_user_id": 1,
    ...
}
```

Valuse of `LegacyUser.id` or `User.legacy_user.id` should be visible in request.

Whats more `email` field have to be unique altogether in `LegacyUser` and `User`

Is this possible to have two User Authorization models? `AUTH_USER_MODEL` only enables me to have one such a model

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'api.LegacyUser'
```

The solution which came to my mind (to archive backward-compatible apps) is to copy current passwords and emails from `LegacyUser` to the new model `User` model and mark them as the most privileges.

Having synchronized passwords for both new and legacy system is also a must so I can use some stored procedure, that changes the password in both places on the update, in the database? For me, it smells very bad and maybe there is some other way to do this without synchronizing these passwords or just using two tables for authorization?

> Edit: To solve this issue I have created MySQL view with unified user data needed only for authorization like:
>
> ```
> CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW unified_user AS
>     SELECT email as email, password as password, is_active as is_active, last_login as last_login
>     FROM user
>     UNION ALL
>     SELECT email as email, password as password, 1 as is_active, null as last_login
>     FROM legacy_user;
> ```
>
> So synchronization of passwords will be done automatically as view will be updated

Comment: What is the problem if we migrate all legacy user to new User model and provide most privileges? What is the reason for synchronization of password?? Please elaborate on it.

Comment: The problem with this is that It has to be backward-compatible with the old table. 
Let's assume that user change password on the legacy system using LegacyUser table then password to the new and old system will be desynchronized.

I want to avoid hard migration. It will be better for me to slowly migrate to the new system leaving functionality of old system

Comment: Hope I get your problem partially. Will PHP and Django will communicate via REST API? 
The request coming from PHP to django is for legacy user authentication. Right?
Valuse of LegacyUser.id or User.legacy_user.id should be visible in request. The 3 json payloads that you have posted are request payload. Right? 
r u using Django REST Framework?

Comment: Both Legacy and New system provide REST API communication with the frontend app. The New system should provide old functionality of the system adding new features.

I'm using Django REST Framework. What's more I would like to provide session-based authorization for Swagger aka [yasg](https://github.com/axnsan12/drf-yasg) and [simplejwt](https://github.com/davesque/django-rest-framework-simplejwt) for endpoints security. 

Communication between Legacy and New system can only be done on the database (no HTTP calls between them)

The new system has to implement authorization on his own

Answer (score 1):

You need a flag to differentiate auth for legacy users and new user.
Let me focus on Session-based auth.

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
'common.auth.backends.CustomUserBackend'
```

]

And remove it `django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware` from middlewares and place your CustomAuthenticationMiddleware.

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
   ...
    'Your CustomAuthenticationMiddleware',
   ....
]
```

at `CustomAuthenticationMiddleware`, attach your user based on the session variable.

implement those methods for class `CustomUserBackend`. Please read [Auth](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/auth/#module-django.contrib.auth.backends)

```
def get_user(self, user_id):
    # read is_legacy_user from session
    # Try to get user based on session is_legacy_user
    # Note that this method is called in CustomAuthenticationMiddleware middleware. 
    # and you have to read from 2 separate table. Session is your friend to differentiate which table we need to fetch.
def authenticate(self, request, email, password, is_legacy_user):
    if is_legacy_user:
       #write the logic for legacy user.
    else:
       #write the logic for new user.
```

From view call the `authenticate` function (`from django.contrib.auth import authenticate`).

For legacy user

```
user = authenticate(email, password, is_legacy_user=True)
# Store the user ID in session as well as is_legacy_user value
```

For new user

```
authenticate(email, password, is_legacy_user=False)
# Store the user ID in session as well as is_legacy_user value
```

I hope this is how you will solve the session-based auth issue. If that work; will move to Token-based.

Answer (score 0):

You want to look at [a https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/. You can have as many different ways to authenticate as you wish. Part of the information stored in the Session record is which authentication backend was used successfully. It's slightly involved, but they give you all of the control necessary to do pretty much whatever you like.

I used this on a system a number of years ago where the primary user/password information was coming from an external subscription management server. If the user/pass did not work on the normal User-auth system, I checked a different system. If it succeeded, I created a new User on the fly.